# Experimenting with writing Rock Paper Scissors game using HTML, css Bootstrap4 and JavaScript and cannot get my function to chose new image to work

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

In my class we were creating a program to provide images of dice and have them roll random numbers when the refresh button was clicked. We were practicing using querySelector and setAttribute. I thought it would be good for my learning to expand the lesson to do paper rock scissors so I could get more familiar with the coding.  However, I cannot get my code to run through the functions that will display the picture of the paper, rock or scissors that is associated with randomNumber1 or randomNumber2.  I tried using bootstrap4 and then just javascript and don't know what I'm doing wrong since I believe in my class we used almost the same code format for the random rolling of two dice, but only used js, css and html5 without using bootstrap.

First I tried writing the code using Bootstrap4, and everything appeared to be working correctly until I added in the function for randomizing the rolling of the dice by clicking refresh.  Then I thought, maybe since I can't get bootstrap to work, I should try it in regular javascript and get it running.  The code will not run there either.  I am puzzled and have spent over a day trying to find answers to my problem.  Below I have included the first set of code I created using bootstrap4 and the second set using just javascript.  In both programs, the rock image that I just want to have take up space when the program is started, shows up so I know there is contact between the images folder and the program, but I don[t know why I cant't get the pictures to change once I click refresh.

### First code using Bootstrap 4

```
    <!-- css stylesheet -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesPractice2.css">
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">

        <h1 class="header">Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>
        <div class = "decision">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">Need to make a decision???</h2>
        </div>

        <div class = "players">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">Player 1</h2>
          <img class = "responsive img1" src = "images/rockPaperScissors3.png">
        </div>

        <div class="players">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">Player 2</h2>
          <img class = "responsive img2" src = "images/rockPaperScissors3.png">
        </div>

        <div class = "whoWins">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">And the winner is . . .</h2>
        </div>

      </div>

    <script src = "rockPaperScissors.js" charset = "utf-8"></script>

    </body>
```

JavaScript

```
    // FIRST PLAYER CREATE RANDOM NUMBER
    var randomNumber1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) + 1;
    // SECOND PLAYER CREATE RANDOM NUMBER
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    function images1() {
      if(randomNumber1 === 1) {
        document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors1.png");
      }
      else if(randomNumber1 === 2) {
        document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors2.png");
      }
      else if(randomNumber1 === 3) {
        document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors3.png");
      }
    }
```

and I stopped there because img1 was not randomizing and I could not find the answer in research.

### 2nd Programming No Bootstrap used.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesPractice2.css">
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">

        <h1 class="header">Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>
        <div class = "decision">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">Need to make a decision???</h2>
        </div>

        <div class = "players">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">Player 1</h2>
          <img class = "responsive img1" src = "images/rockPaperScissors3.png">
        </div>

        <div class="players">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">Player 2</h2>
          <img class = "responsive img2" src = "images/rockPaperScissors3.png">
        </div>

        <div class = "whoWins">
          <h2 class = "subtopic">And the winner is . . .</h2>
        </div>

      </div>

    <script src = "rockPaperScissors.js" charset = "utf-8"></script>

    </body>
```

Both programs included the `</html>` tag

CSS

```css
    body {
      font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
      background-color: #76fc23;
      color: #2357fc;
    }

    .container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .title {
      margin-top: 4.0rem;
    }

    .header {
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 5rem;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }

    h2 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .players {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 2rem 3rem 2rem;
    }

    .player1 {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
      /* text-align: right;
      padding-right: 5%; */
    }

    .player2 {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
      /* text-align: left;
      padding-left: 5%; */
    }

    .img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
      // FIRST PLAYER CREATE RANDOM NUMBER
      var randomNumber1 = Math.random();
      randomNumber1 = Math.random() * 6;
      randomNumber1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)) + 1;
      // SECOND PLAYER CREATE RANDOM NUMBER
      var randomNumber2 = Math.random();
      randomNumber2 = Math.random() * 6;
      randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    function images1() {
      if(randomNumber1 === 1) {
        document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors1.png");
      }
      else if(randomNumber1 === 2) {
        document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors2.png");
      }
      else{
        document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors3.png");
      }
    }

    function images2() {
      if(randomNumber2 === 1) {
        document.querySelector(".img2").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors1.png");
      }
      else if(randomNumber2 === 2) {
        document.querySelector(".img2").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors2.png");
      }
      else{
        document.querySelector(".img2").setAttribute("src", "images/rockPaperScissors3.png");
      }
    }


    images1();
    images2();
```

In the javascript, I want my functions to change the images to the ones listed if randomNumber1 or randomNumber2 equal 1, 2 or 3.  Instead, they just stay on the original image from html.  I also need to use querySelector and setAttribute in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically change an image's `src` attribute because `img` is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element). This means that an `img` isn't part of the document, but an external resource that's inserted into the document. If the image doesn't exist in a real sense, then it can't be inserted.

You need to [construct a new image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) via `new Image()` in your JS to be able to replace the existing image.